# Is it possible to deploy modified changes via VSCode to the sandbox like in scratch org?

Tags: deployment, sandbox, scratch-org, vs-code

In VSCode I can only deploy changes from my project to the scratch org. Is it possible to do the same when VSCode is connected to the standard sandbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use `sfdx force:source:deploy`and pass the username or alias of the environment to deploy to using the `-u` flag

Comment: This would deploy everything, not just modifications, right?

Comment: @PhilW Yep, but that's just the reality of deploying to a non-scratch org using the CLI (and, I imagine, part of the reason Salesforce encourages SFDX projects to only contain small and independently testable chunks of functionality). You can maintain a package.xml file to limit what gets deployed (using the `-x` flag)

Comment: @DerekF as I know dx push does the deployment changes only. Not all source.

Comment: @EugeneVabishchevich I'm not talking about `force:source:push`, my answer covers `force:source:deploy`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can be done. Its called as Org Development Model. Sandbox and Prod dont support dx format. They support metadata format. You can create a project with manifest and use VS code to deploy in sanboxes.

Or, convert sfdx to metadata format and then deploy.

Src: https://forcedotcom.github.io/salesforcedx-vscode/articles/user-guide/org-development-model

Src: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/org-development-model

Comment: Better still, use IntelliJ IDEA and Illuminated Cloud 2 instead of VSCode. You can do both without having to restructure your project code IIRC. :)

Comment: I use intellij, but people don't prefer as its paid?

Comment: @PhilW IntelliJ IDEA + Illuminated Cloud 2 are not free. And we want to work with standard Salesforce solutions. Right now it's VSCode + Salesforce plugin.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal as an example: I have added changes to my class. When I click deploy source to the org I want to deploy just this class. I didn't get it from the links above.

Comment: You have to know the list of files to deploy then you need to set up the package.xml as @DerekF suggested - or you need to use the path specifications on the CLI.

Comment: @EugeneVabishchevich if you want a better developer experience and to be more productive I strongly recommend IDEA+IC2. Just because Salesforce provide their VSCode plugin doesn't mean you should slavishly stick to it IMHO. IC2 uses only standard Salesforce functionality (meta API etc.) under the hood so is fully compatible. It just happens to provide an easier to use and more productive UX. (Yes, there are cost implications, but if you are serious about Salesforce development your company should be able to stretch to it!)